How to Capture and Crop an Image to a Focus Frame Using React Native Vision Camera?
I'm working on a React Native application where I need to capture an image using the Vision Camera library and then display only the content that's within a predefined focus frame. The goal is to crop the captured image to fit the focus frame's dimensions. Here's what I've done so far:
Set up the camera using React Native Vision Camera.
Created a focus frame overlay using a View component to help guide users.
Captured an image using the camera when the user presses a button.
What I need help with:
How do I implement the cropImageToFrame function to crop the captured image to the dimensions of the focus frame? Are there existing libraries or methods I should use to achieve this in React Native, or should I handle this natively on Android and iOS?
Instagram uses this function to post images using camera
I'd appreciate any guidance on how to properly crop the image or any resources you could point me to. Thank you!
